# I have been using elementary Os for almost 6 months

Tags: elementary-project

I have been using elementary Os for almost 6 months. Everything is fine and i love it, but here is the question 
is Elementary Os discontinued ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not discontinued, the latest version is 5.0 Juno, based on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I must remind you that eOS is based only on the LTS versions of ubuntu. So when another LTS version of ubuntu comes out we will see some new version of eOS.

Comment: thank you brother

Comment: u re welcome, Do not forget to mark your question as resolved.